# xsd xpath predicates to select node with matching attribute

Tags: xml, xsd

In identity constraint, I need to select a element *"arg"* having specific attribute value *[@type='parse']*.
But I am getting error,
    **The expression 'action//@type' is not valid with respect to the XPath subset supported by XML Schema.**

For the following statement,

`<xs:selector xpath="action/arg[@type='parse']"/>`

The complete XSD file is,

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xs:element name="test">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="page" maxOccurs="32"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="page">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="parse"/>
            <xs:element ref="action"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>            

      <xs:keyref name="arg_key_ref" refer="assert_key">
         <xs:selector xpath="action/arg[@type='parse']"/>
         <xs:field xpath="."/>
       </xs:keyref>

       <xs:key name="assert_key">
         <xs:selector xpath="parse/parameter/name"/>
         <xs:field xpath="."/>
       </xs:key>

   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="parse">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="parameter" maxOccurs="32"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="action">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>            
            <xs:element ref="arg" maxOccurs="32"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="parameter">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="arg">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
               <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
         </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Thanks in advance,
Kishore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `selector` and `field` of an XML Schema 1.0 key or keyref only support a restricted subset of XPath [as defined in the schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#coss-identity-constraint).  For `selector`:

```
[1]  Selector ::=   Path ( '|' Path )*
[2]  Path     ::=   ('.//')? Step ( '/' Step )*
[3]  Step     ::=   '.' | NameTest
[4]  NameTest ::=   QName | '*' | NCName ':' '*'
```

In particular this does *not* support predicates.

If you can use XML Schema 1.1 then that supports the full XPath 2.0 language.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ian. libxml2 doesn't support XPath 2.0. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: @NandkishorBiradar if you can modify the XML format a bit (e.g. use an element named `parseArg` instead of `arg type="parse"`) then that's the easiest approach, but if the format is fixed you'd have to look into schematron rules to validate the cross reference.